# Autoplay on "onclick" stuck

Tags: javascript, html, audio, onclick

The build-in browser audio player starts automatically with the following code...

```
function play(){
var audio = document.getElementById("myaudio");
audio.play();
}
```

but if i do...

```
function play(){
var audio = document.getElementById("myaudio") .style.display="block";
audio.play();
}
```

...the player doesn´t start anymore. - I have the player on style="display:none" so that i can let it show onclick="play()" from a image.

Please help... thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your second example isn't valid javascript. Try:

```
function play(){
    var audio = document.getElementById("myaudio");
    audio.style.display="block";
    audio.play();
}
```

Next time, have a look in the browser console (Usually Ctrl-Shift-K or F12), it'll show you syntax (and other) errors.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the following code?

```
function play(){
var audio = document.getElementById("myaudio");
audio.style.display="block";
audio.play();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question of *why* the second doesn't work, JS first does

```
document.getElementById("myaudio") .style.display="block"
```

then sets `audio` to the return value. But that is `'block'`, not the player, and you can't call `'block'.play()`.